# docker: "Error response from daemon: missing signature key"

Tags: docker

I deleted some images from our registry's storage backend and caused some issues. So, in order to restore the last, "latest"-tagged image, I pushed it from my local Docker, since I know it is the most up-to-date. All of the other systems in the network that need it have suddenly started failing with a new error: "Error response from daemon: missing signature key".

There appeared to be no useful suggestions or documentation online. I've inspected the latest image and its parent, and its parent, etc.. from my local host, and I am able to see information on all of them. This error seems to be specific to pulling/running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back into the storage backend, erased my newly-pushed image and fully restored the original set of images that I had removed. However, I still had the same issue from all tested systems, including my local one. It has to do with some pre-pull lookup that is performed that involves more than a simple "docker inspect" does.

I assumed that there must be something broken with the tip image, so I just used our image-building process to do another "docker build", "docker tag", and "docker push", which both tags (and pushes) a version tag and updates the "latest" tag to point to it. That did it. Suddenly every host/daemon could pull again.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this error on a system simply because the daemon there was too old (and I was connecting to it with a newer client).

Comment: Hello, do you know why being too old would cause an issue in the signature key?

Comment: @vcmorini, I didn't really investigate, but I suppose the protocol has simply changed too much between the two versions.

Comment: Hello, I have upgraded my Docker version in RHEL 7 with the help of this article in IBM: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/fci/6.5.0?topic=steps-upgrading-docker#d37886e89.

To remove the old docker version:
`sudo yum remove docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin`
 
`sudo systemctl stop docker`
`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker`
`sudo systemctl start docker`
 
`sudo yum autoremove`